# Why $n! \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{(n-k)!} = n! \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, permutations, factorial

According to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/wiki/Number_of_arrangements), the formula for getting the number of arrangements of any subset of `n` distinct objects is:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}k! = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}k!\\ = n!\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{(n-k)!} = n! \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$$

From the first expression to the second expression is the formula for n choose k. From the second expression to the third expression, k! is cancelled out. But next why do we have $\frac{1}{(n-k)!} = \frac{1}{k!}$?

Comment: The fact that $\sum a_i=\sum b_i$ does not tell you that $a_i=b_i$.  Here note that the sequence $\{n-k\}$ is the reverse of the sequence $\{k\}$.

Comment: Write the sum for (say) $n=4$ and you'll see it immediately!

Comment: For a sum of finitely many terms, you can rearrange the sequence of terms without affecting the sum.  For a sum of infinitely many terms, you would need to first confirm that the sum of the absolute values of the terms converges to a finite value, because otherwise you may reach a contradiction after relying upon the assumption that the value of the sum is unaffected by adding in a different order or sequence.

Comment: @lulu Thank you. That's what tripped me up.

Comment: It's just a consequence of $a+b=b+a$ :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what happens for Sigma  $  n!\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{(n-k)!} = n! \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}  $ its suffice to show $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{(n-k)!} =  \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$$
so put the numbers
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{(n-k)!}=\frac 1{(n-0)!}+\frac 1{(n-1)!}+\frac 1{(n-1)!}+\cdots+\frac 1{(n-n)!}=\\\frac 1{(n)!}+\frac 1{(n-1)!}+\frac 1{(n-1)!}+\cdots+\frac 1{(0)!}$$ and  other Sigma $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}=\frac 1{0!}+\frac 1{1!}+\frac 1{2!}+\cdots+\frac 1{(n-1)!}+\frac 1{n!}$$ and both are the same